# Query to find how many customers have made an order

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

So I have two tables one is **customer** and the other is **order**.
The customer table has a region field. Customers can have multiple orders or no orders.

I tried this:

```
SELECT customer.region, count(*) 
  FROM customer 
  LEFT JOIN order ON order.cid = customer.id 
 GROUP BY customer.region 
 ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Unfortunately this doesn't **exclude** customers with no orders and also counts customers multiple times if they have multiple orders.

Comment: So you want to find per customer per region or per customer and the count of order ? And also provide the table structures ?

Comment: I want to see how many customers ordered something in each region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
SELECT region, count(DISTINCT customer.id) 
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN order ON order.cid = customer.id 
GROUP BY region
```

Essentially the `INNER` join only returns customers who have placed an order and the `DISTINCT` will only bring back a customer.id once so if a customer has placed multiple orders this will just bring back their customer.id once.

As Michael Y rightly said if you want to bring back all the regions regardless of if they have any matching orders then replace the `INNER` with a `LEFT`

Comment: Oh this might work. Hold on. EDIT: This is perfect. Thank you! I will accept it in 5m when it lets me >.>

Comment: Lol sorry, I got caught up.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN if you want to see the regions with 0 orders as well (regions with most orders on top):

```
SELECT region, count(DISTINCT customer.id) 
FROM customer 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN order ON order.cid = customer.id 
GROUP BY region
ORDER BY 2 desc
```